# how to pass a callback function in another function in swift?

Tags: swift, xcode

so i'm doing my first app, 
and i want to do a function that will be a uniform funciton to sevral places in the system, and not belong to only one specific class.
Is there a way for me to pass a callback function as a parameter to another function ?

here is just a demonstration of what i mean.

```
ClassA {

   func classAcallbackFunction (displayString: String) {
     print (displayString)
   }


   ClassB().classBFunction(classAcallbackFunction())


}

ClassB {

   func classBfunction (myCallbackfunc: func) {
     mycallbackfunc("all is working !!!")
   }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The parameter you have declared is not correct. Replace it with something like this:

```
func classBFunction(_ completion: (String) -> Void) {
    completion("all working")
}
```

Like shared by [regina_fallangi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3565291/regina-fallangi) in the comments, callbacks are usually called `completion` handlers, which is why I replaced the names accordingly.

Extra Credit:

If you only want to *optionally* pass a function, you could do this:

```
func classBFunction(_ completion: ((String) -> Void)? = nil) {
    completion?("all working")
}
```

Now you could also just call `classBFunction()`.

Comment: A small nit: callback is the theoretical name and the one used predominantly in JavaScript. Swift uses `completion`, which gives it a different meaning. You should always call your `completion`, no matter what happens. If there is an error, the you should call `completion(error)`, if there was success, `completion(true)`, etc.

Comment: Another small nit: Underscore and parameter label are Swift 2 legacy, in Swift 3+ it's simply `(String) -> Void` as the parameter label is not used anyway.

Comment: If a `completion` should always be called, what should we call a high order function that isn't necessarily called, like a button click. A callback?

Comment: @vadian the parameter label may be important in situations where the type itself doesn't clarify what function should be passed.